# html Table td element lost focus handling

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having a html table. Each row of this table is having two text box created by using the following syntax

```
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Temprature, new { size = 4, data_Target_Input = "Temprature" })

            </td>
```

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Temprature, new { size = 4, data_Target_Input = "Temprature" })

One text box takes the value in celcius and one in farenhite. So when i entre the value of temprature in celcius box i want the Farenhite box to have the converted value when my celcius box lost the focus. But i am unable to handle the focus

Comment: you calculating the values from javascript?

Comment: yes i want to calculate the value from javascript , but the javascript code should be added to some handler. That handler is the main problem which i am unable to invoke.

Comment: Arun added the answer check with that

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#celciusBox').blur(function() {
  var temp = // code for data conversion
  $('#farenhiteBox').val(temp)
});
```

Comment: celciusBox is the name of box or id of box ?. The reason i am asking is this because The td element can not have a name.

Comment: in your case "Temprature" is the id.

 Use $('#Temprature').

Comment: tried the following .. but not working.<script type="text/javascript">

    debugger
    $('#Temprature').blur(function () {
        var temp = 5; // code for data conversion
        $('#Temprature1').val(temp);
    });
</script> 
}

Comment: $('#Temprature').blur(function () { 
    var temp =  $('#Temprature').val() * 1.8 + 32;
    $('#Temprature1').val(temp); }); 
    }

Comment: the issue is that the blur function is not getting called.  the code logic for temprature conversion does not matter.

Comment: No i did not import. What does that mean?

Comment: insert this line before other scripts...

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this one 

<script>
    $('#Temprature').blur(function () { 
    var temp =  $('#Temprature').val() * 1.8 + 32;
    $('#Temprature1').val(temp); }); 
    }
</script>
```